# Using igraph in python for community detection and writing community number for each node to CSV

Tags: python, igraph, hierarchical-clustering

I have an network that I would like to analyze using the `edge_betweenness` community detection algorithm in igraph.  I'm familiar with NetworkX, but am trying to learning igraph because of it's additional community detection methods over NetworkX.

My ultimate goal is to run `edge_betweenness` community detection and find the optimal number of communities and write a CSV with community membership for each node in the graph.

Below is my code as it currently stands.  Any help figuring out community membership is greatly appreciated.

**input data ('network.txt'):**

```
1 2
2 3
2 7
3 1
4 2
4 6
5 4
5 6
7 4
7 8
8 9
9 7
10 7
10 8
10 9
```

**iGraph code**

```
import igraph

# load data into a graph
g = igraph.Graph.Read_Ncol('network.txt')

# plot graph
igraph.plot(g)
```

[image: igraph.plot(g)]

```
# identify communities
communities = igraph.community_edge_betweenness()

# not really sure what to do next
num_communities = communities.optimal_count
communities.as_clustering(num_communities)
```

**What do I need to do to find the optimal number of communities and write which community each node in the graph belongs to a list?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are on the right track; the optimal number of communities (where "optimal" is defined as "the number of communities that maximizes the modularity score) can be retrieved by `communities.optimal_count` and the community structure can be converted into a flat disjoint clustering using `communities.as_clustering(num_communities)`. Actually, the number of communities can be omitted if it happens to be equal to `communities.optimal_count`. Once you've done that, you get a `VertexClustering` object with a `membership` property which gives you the cluster index for each vertex in the graph.

For sake of clarity, I'm renaming your `communities` variable to `dendrogram` because the edge betweenness community detection algorithm actually produces a dendrogram::

```
# calculate dendrogram
dendrogram = graph.community_edge_betweenness()
# convert it into a flat clustering
clusters = dendrogram.as_clustering()
# get the membership vector
membership = clusters.membership
```

Now we can start writing the membership vector along with the node names into a CSV file::

```
import csv
from itertools import izip

writer = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "wb"))
for name, membership in izip(graph.vs["name"], membership):
    writer.writerow([name, membership])
```

If you are using Python 3, use `zip` instead of `izip` and there is no need to import `itertools`.