# Type of object when writing csv in Python

Tags: python, igraph

I am trying to use igraph to find the optimal number of communities for each nodes and found a good answer here [Using iGraph in python for community detection and writing community number for each node to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254151/using-igraph-in-python-for-community-detection-and-writing-community-number-for)

I tried the code he provided but run into error

`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Here's the code I used

```
import igraph
import csv

g = igraph.Graph.Read_Ncol('data.txt')
dendrogram = g.community_edge_betweenness()
clusters = dendrogram.as_clustering()
membership = clusters.membership

writer = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "wb"))
for name, membership in zip(g.vs["name"], membership):
    writer.writerow([name, membership])
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to write a string into a file opened in `"wb"` mode, which only allows one to write `bytes` into it, not `str`ings.

Comment: How should I modify it to write `str`ings?

Comment: Open it in 'w' mode.

Comment: instead of `writer = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "wb"))`, use `writer = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "w"))`. `w` instead of `wb`.